# Не загружаются css и jr файлы в Spring

Tags: css, spring, intellij-idea, mvc, tomcat

Ребята прощу помочь с проблемой....Уже несколько дней не могу решить проблему...При открытии Страницы через ЛокалХост не видны css и js файлы.Использовал почти все методы которые предусмотрены в интернете.Но никак...
П.С При открытии home.html через обычный браузер css работает.
Привожу пример на основе простого примера.

[image: Привожу пример на основе картинкаи]

Comment: Да и еще.Пробовал различные конфигурации.Даже заново загрузил и установил томкат.поменял браузер Подумал проблема связана с кешом браузера...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё что находится в папке `static` будет находится в корне сайта и подключается так:

`<link rel="stylesheet" th:href ="/css/css1.css"/>`

Где-то в недрах спринга есть такой код:

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
    "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
    "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
```

Папка `static` копируется maven'ом в папку `target/classes`, возможно, если запускаете через идею, она не копируется туда.

Comment: Из за этой проблемы я уже распустил руки.Ваш ответ был верен я его проверил работает.Благодарю вас.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте если css или js файл находится внутри пакета static не нужно добавить это `../`,потому что  файл который находится внутри static а будет доступно в пакете templates уберите это `../` надеюсь получится если нет попробуйте добавить этот строка

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}../static/css/сss1.css">` если тоже не получилось попробуйте это

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href ="@{/css/css1.css}"/>
```